# Need awk assistance to print a section of a file

Tags: linux, awk

I am looking for help using awk to print only a section of a text file that begins with a keyword (TC024) and ends with a blank line but then also print the following 2 lines after the blank line.  What I have been trying is as follows but it isn't working:

```
 awk '/TC024/{p=1} p; p && /^$/{c++} p && c<=2{print} c==3{exit}' test1.txt
```

Comment: Please include a reduced sample text file so readers can copy/paste and be sure they're going to help solve your problem. Good attempt at solving your problem! Good luck.

Comment: What shellter said: add sample data. How can there be two more lines if the file ENDS with a blank line?

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk '
    /TC024/ {p=1}               # set flag if the pattern matches
    p || c&&c-- {print}         # print if flag is set or c is positive
    p && /^$/ {p=0; c=2}        # reset flag and set counter c on the blank line
' test1.txt
```

or a one-liner:

```
awk '/TC024/{p=1} p||c&&c--{print} p&&/^$/{p=0;c=2}' test1.txt
```

Example of `test1.txt`:

```
TC024
foo
bar
baz

1st footer
2nd footer
3rd footer
TC024
lorem
ipsum

1st footer2
2nd footer2
3rd footer2
```

Output:

```
TC024
foo
bar
baz

1st footer
2nd footer
TC024
lorem
ipsum

1st footer2
2nd footer2
```

Answer (score 0):

> print the following 2 lines

I suggest using [`getline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Plain-Getline.html) for that purpose, consider following simple example, let `file.txt` content be

```
DO NOT PRINT
TC024
PRINT THIS
PRINT THIS

PRINT ALSO THIS
PRINT ALSO THIS
DO NOT PRINT
```

then

```
awk '/TC024/{p=1}p{print}/^$/{getline;print;getline;print;p=0}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
TC024
PRINT THIS
PRINT THIS

PRINT ALSO THIS
PRINT ALSO THIS
```

Explanation: after encountering `TC024` set flag `p` to `1`, `print` current line if `p` is set to non-zero, when encountering empty line `print` two following lines using `getline` and `print` then set `p` to `0`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the same approach conceptually, but converting all the pattern-action blocks to a single `range pattern`,

and by embedding the `ON / OFF` toggling of indicator flag(s) within the `range pattern`s themselves, *other than the* **`BEGIN { }`** *block that I used to define default flag values*, one can even do without user-defined action blocks altogether :

```
mawk 'BEGIN {   _ = __ = (_ = 3) ^ (_^_-- + (___ = _)) 
            } /TC024/ && (_ = __), (/./ ? _ : _ = ___ + NR) == NR'
```

---

```
TC024
foo
bar
baz

1st footer
2nd footer
TC024
lorem
ipsum

1st footer2
2nd footer2
```